# How to change the dot (if more than 2) in java?

Tags: java, string

I'd like to change the dot to `""` if more than 2. So I mean that `hel.lo.txt` or `he.l.l.o.txt` then returns `hello.txt`.

I wrote this where not  begin end with "."

```
int pointindex = filename.indexOf(".");
if (pointindex==0){     
    System.out.println("Point index :"+pointindex);
    String mystring=filename.substring(pointindex, 1);
    filename=filename.replace(mystring, "");
}

//end is "."
int extensions = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
String newfilename=filename.substring(extensions);
System.out.println(newfilename.length());
if ( newfilename.length()<2){
    System.out.println("Dont have extension, so filename end is"+".");
    int dotidx=filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    filename=filename.substring(0,dotidx);
    System.out.println(filename);
}
```

Comment: You already have everything you need: `indexOf()`, `replace()`, `lastIndexOf()`. Just think a bit about what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply manipulate `String` here

```
String str = "he.l.l.o.txt";
int lastIndexOfDot = str.lastIndexOf('.');
String str1 = str.substring(0, lastIndexOfDot + 1);
String str2 = str.substring(lastIndexOfDot, str.length());
str = str1.replace(".", "") + str2;
System.out.println(str);
```

***OUTPUT :***

```
hello.txt
```

*NOTE: You can create a method which take `String` as an argument and return the required `String`.*

Comment: thank you, I tried it already  in some ways but but did not want to succeed. It deleted all of the dots or so on...